# Evaluate postfix expression getting Wrong Output

Tags: python, postfix-mta

Sample Test Cases
Test Case 1:
Expected Output:
Enter·Postfix·expression231*+9-
Result·of·Postfix·expression·231*+9-·is·-4

Test Case 2:
Expected Output:
Enter·Postfix·expression34+22/*
Result·of·Postfix·expression·34+22/*·is·7

```
    class Evaluate:
        def __init__(self, capacity):
            self.top = -1
            self.capacity = capacity
            self.array = []
            
        def isEmpty(self):
            return True if self.top == -1 else False
        
        def peek(self):
            return self.array[-1]
            
        def pop(self):
            if not self.isEmpty():
                self.top -= 1
                return self.array.pop()
            else:
                return "$"
                
        def push(self, op):
            self.top += 1
            self.array.append(op)
            
        def evaluatePostfix(self, exp):
            for i in exp:
                
                if i.isdigit():
                    self.push(i)
                    
                else:
                    val1 = self.pop()
                    val2 = self.pop()
                    self.push(str(eval(val2 + i + val1)))
                    
            return int(self.pop())
            
    exp = input('Enter Postfix expression')
    obj = Evaluate(len(exp))
    print("Result of Postfix expression", exp , "is %d" % (obj.evaluatePostfix(exp)))


Test Case 1: Getting Correct Output = Result·of·Postfix·expression·231*+9-·is·-4
But in Test Case 2: I will get an Error


**Please let me know Where iam wrong...**
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it seems to give me `7.0` for test case 2, so it seems to work. However, the string formatting can't convert `7.0` to an integer (`%d`), so I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "69147707.py", line 39, in <module>
    print("Result of Postfix expression", exp , "is %d" % (obj.evaluatePostfix(exp)))
  File "69147707.py", line 35, in evaluatePostfix
    return int(self.pop())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.0'
```

Maybe try casting the solution to an int using `int()`?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).